# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with Kotlin data class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been debugging this for hours now but nothing seems to work, I keep getting this runtime exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.model.SMSList"
```

This is the class it is referring to :

```
 package inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.model

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.io.Serializable

@Entity(tableName = "phonesms")
data class SMSList(
    val address: String,
    val body: String,
    val smsdate: String,
    val bankcode: String,
    val banktransactioncode: String,
    val bankname:String,
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    var isSMS:Boolean = true,
    var isSent:Boolean = false,
    var accountNumber:String ="",
    var transactionType:String="",
    var narration:String ="",
    var transactionDate:String ="",
    var balance:String = "",
    var transactionAmount:String = "",
    var transactionTime:String =""
):Serializable
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="inc.qucoon.nativeveezah">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <application
    android:name=".app.VeezahAppliation"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<receiver
        android:name=".broadcastreceiver.SMSBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

<activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

    </activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.ImagePickerActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".activity.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/EnrolTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:largeHeap="true">


    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activity.FirstActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
<receiver
        android:name=".broadcastreceiver.ConnectivityReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

 </application>
</manifest>
```

ReadSMSRepository:

```
package inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.repository
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.work.*
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.qucoon.smsservices.local.dao.SMSDao
import com.qucoon.smsservices.services.ReadAllSMSFromBankWorker
import com.tinder.scarlet.WebSocket
import inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.model.SMSList
import inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.model.response.Data
import inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.services.RefreshBankListWorker
import inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.socket.GdaxService
import inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.socket.SocketData
import inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.utils.SMSUtils
import inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.utils.closeCursor
import inc.qucoon.nativeveezah.utils.convertToDate
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import timber.log.Timber
import java.lang.Exception

//This was the initial usage that was working before i added the socket
sms.add(SMSList(address = address, id = id, body = message, smsdate = longDate.convertToDate("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"),
                                    bankname = bank.bankname, banktransactioncode = bank.transactioncode, bankcode = bank.bankcode,
                                    accountNumber = SMSUtils.getAccountNumber(message), transactionTime = SMSUtils.getTransactionTime(message),
                                    transactionDate = SMSUtils.getTransactionDate(message), transactionAmount = amountAndBalance.first, balance = amountAndBalance.second,
                                    transactionType = SMSUtils.getTransactionType(message)
                            ))


 gdaxService.observeAlerts()
            .subscribe({ websocketData ->
                val transactioon = websocketData.map { SMSList(id = "a${it.id}",address = it.transactionbankcode,body = it.narration,smsdate = it.date,
                  bankcode = it.bankcode,banktransactioncode = it.transactionbankcode,balance = it.balance,bankname = it.bankname,
                  accountNumber = it.custaccountnumber,transactionType = it.drcr,transactionAmount = it.amount,transactionDate = it.date,transactionTime = it.time,narration = it.narration,
                  isSMS = false
          ) }
            },{e -> Timber.e(e)})
```

It was working right before I added Tinder Scarlet Websocket to my project.
Multidex is enabled on the project, I removed proguard in case that was the issue, I've also tried invalidating caches and restarting as well as rebuilding the project, also I disabled instant run but the error keeps showing.

Comment: post the **full file** ! along with the import statements for `SMSList.kt`

Comment: Please share your manifest file.

Comment: In which class you are facing this error ?

Comment: @AbdulRahmanShamair the manifest has been added

Comment: @KhizarHayat Im facing the error anywhere i am using the Data class

Comment: @Bolu what is the file name of this ? It could be that file name AND class inside i.e SMSList in this case are mismatched

Comment: In your manifest, right after application tag, you have
          android: name=".app.VeezahAppliation"
Can you tell which parent class this class is inheriting from

Comment: @KhizarHayat i am using the dataclass in two different places in one repository  : ReadSMSRepository it was working right before i added the Scarlet WebSocket i'll add the usage to the question now

Comment: @AbdulRahmanShamair it is inheriting from MultiDexApplication